# Swift use of break in guard statement

Tags: swift, if-statement, option-type, guard

I'm trying to use `break` in an `guard` statement, but the compiler tells me

> 'break' is only allowed inside a loop, if, do, or switch

Is possible to write something like in this snippet (this is just an MCV)?

```
   func test(string: String?, x: Int) {
        print("Function Scope BEGIN")
        if x > 4 {
            guard let pr = string else { break }
            print(pr)
        }
        else {
            print("Not")
        }
        print("Function Scope END")
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect the `break` will do? (i.e. what is the expected output of `test(nil, x: 5)`?)

Comment: You're essentially using a `goto` here. Consider refactoring.

Comment: @kennytm this is not the actual code, this an example, the expected result is to not print pr but print "Function Scope END"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  You can use unlabeled `break` statements inside loops, but not inside an `if` block.  You *can* use labeled `break` statements though. For example, this version of your code will work:

```
func test(string: String?, x: Int) {
    print("Function Scope BEGIN")
    someLabel: if x > 4 {
        guard let pr = string else { break someLabel }
        print(pr)
    }
    else {
        print("Not")
    }
    print("Function Scope END")
}
```

Comment: This is essentially a `goto`. IT's a pretty strong indication that this should be designed better.

Comment: @AMomchilov  That is a valid concern, but the question was if it's possible, not whether it's a good design  :)

Comment: Yes, I'm not grilling you for it. Your answer is totally correct, but it's solving a problem that shouldn't exist if it were designed better. I thought it was worth pointing it out.

Comment: @AMomchilov  Agreed :)  It is worth pointing out to the original poster

Comment: Thank you @DanielHall, I've already came across `goto` and I do agree with AMomchilov thst it should be designed better. But as it seems to be only solution your answer is totally correct

Comment: One important point here is that in swift labeled break doesn't work like goto. It jumps to the end of labeled control/loop block.

Answer (score 2):

A `break` statement can only be used inside a `guard let` if the guard-let is inside a loop.

In your use-case, I'd say you should use an `if-let` instead, since the alternative option of `return` is not what is desired.

```
    func test(string: String?, x: Int) {

        print("Function Scope BEGIN")
        if x > 4 {

            if let pr = string { print(pr) }

        }
        else {

            print("Not")
        }
        print("Function Scope END")
    }
```

Comment: It's not accurate that a break statement can only be used inside a `guard-let` if the guard-let is inside a loop